# scrollIntoView Scrolls just too far

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll

I have a page where a scroll bar containing table rows with divs in them is dynamically generated from the database. Each table row acts like a link, sort of like you'd see on a YouTube playlist next to the video player.

When a user visits the page, the option they are on is supposed to go to the top of the scrolling div. This functionality is working. The issue is that it goes just a tad too far. Like the option they are on is about 10px too high. So, the page is visited, the url is used to identify which option was selected and then scrolls that option to the top of the scrolling div. Note: This is not the scroll bar for the window, it is a div with a scrollbar.

I am using this code to make it move the selected option to the top of the div:

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );

var el = document.getElementById(pathArray[5]);

el.scrollIntoView(true);
```

It moves it to the top of the div but about 10 pixels too far up.
Anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: The lack of offset configuration for `scrollIntoView` is troubling.

Comment: @mystrdat There are new CSS properties that deal with this, `scroll-margin` and `scroll-padding`.

Comment: Do you have lazy loaded images or dynamic things that could change in height on scroll?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If it's about 10px, then I guess you could simply manually adjust the containing `div`'s scroll offset like that:

```
el.scrollIntoView(true);
document.getElementById("containingDiv").scrollTop -= 10;
```

Comment: Will this have the same animated effect as `scrollIntoView`?

Comment: @thomas AFAIK, the plain DOM `scrollIntoView` function does not cause animation. Are you talking about the scrollIntoView jQuery plugin?

Comment: That worked man, except it was the wrong direction so all I had to do was change it from += 10 to -= 10 and now it's loading just right, thanks a lot for the help!!!!

Comment: Yep. I was confused. I thought it animated. Sorry!

Comment: It can animate, just add `el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });`. Support isn't great though!

Comment: There's a cross browser polyfill for the smooth behavior – https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll

Comment: I found adding 'block:"enter"' to the options helped for me

Comment: Doesn't work went scrolling to the last row. It should be scrolled all the way down but goes back up by 10px.

Answer (score 346):

## Smooth scroll to the proper position

> [Here is **better answer for the most cases**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665602/scrollintoview-scrolls-just-too-far/56391657#answer-67923821). It uses **scroll-margin** and **scroll-padding** CSS rules.
> The solution below uses `getBoundingClientRect` which triggers an additional forced layout.

Get **correct** `y` coordinate and use `window.scrollTo({top: y, behavior: 'smooth'})`

```
const id = 'profilePhoto';
const yOffset = -10; 
const element = document.getElementById(id);
const y = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset + yOffset;

window.scrollTo({top: y, behavior: 'smooth'});
```

Comment: This is the most correctly answer - we can easly find position of scroll with `jQuery('#el').offset().top` and then to use `window.scrollTo`

Comment: +1 for this solution. It helped me to scroll to the element correctly when I had a container positioned relative with a top offset.

Comment: Anyone coming here using HashLink with React Router, this is what worked for me. In the scroll prop on your HashLink, 
`scroll={el => {
        const yCoordinate = el.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;
        const yOffset = -80; 

        window.scrollTo({
            top: yCoordinate + yOffset,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
      }}`
-- where the offset is 10-15 pixels more than the size of your header just for better spacing

Comment: this CSS might help someone ... scroll-behavior: smooth;

Comment: Only issue with the `getBoundingClientRect` triggers a forced layout / reflow which is a performance bottleneck. That being said, if used with parcimony, it's quite ok !

Comment: @GeorgesA you are right. I have updated my answer and noted that scroll-margin and scroll-padding would be a better solution

Comment: scrollTo does not work for React at the moment. Or at least I have not been able to get it to work as intended.

Comment: @RJA doesn't sound right as it is the default browser feature. I don't see how React may prevent it. And if it does you should definitely see some messages in the console.

Comment: yeah, you'd think it's not throwing any errors, nor is it doing anything,  testing a simple example won't even work. Probably having to do with the batching... I found an alternate solution, might comeback to this later out of curiosity.

Comment: my use case is different as well.. I want to center an accordion when clicked, and it's content is expanded. handling the scroll logic within a useLayoutEffect that's triggered by a state change on click.

Comment: One-liner for inline HTML: `window.scrollTo({top: document.getElementById("yourElem").getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY - 50, behavior: "smooth"});`

Answer (score 211):

## CSS `scroll-margin` and `scroll-padding`

You might want to have a look at new CSS properties [`scroll-padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-padding) and [`scroll-margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin). You can use `scroll-padding` for the scrolling container (`html` in this case), and `scroll-margin` for the element within the container.

For your example, you would want to add `scroll-margin-top` for the element that you want to scroll into view, like this:

```css
.example {
  scroll-margin-top: 10px;
}
```

This affects `scrollIntoView` code, like this code:

```js
const el = document.querySelector(".example");
el.scrollIntoView({block: "start", behavior: "smooth"});
```

This will cause the viewport to scroll to align the top border of the viewport with the top border of the element, but with 10px of additional space. In other words, these properties of the element are taken into account:

- `padding-top`
- `border-top`
- `scroll-margin-top`
- (and *not* `margin-top`)

In addition, if the `html` element has `scroll-padding-top` set, then that is taken into account too.

Comment: If you're using a framework like Vue, you might want to make sure that all changes to the DOM are finished before running `scrollIntoView` by using something like `Vue.nextTick(() => el.scrollIntoView())`

Comment: This is an awesome solution.. which is completely made sense :) Thanks @Flimm

Comment: perfect thanks mate! The selected answer didn't quite work for me.

Comment: Another troublshooting tip: if you're loading a URL with a fragment (for example http://example.com/#test) , then the browser will scroll to the element with that `id` or `name` when the page has loaded, but not before all AJAX has finished loading. If you're causing layout shifts after the page has loaded, navigating to a URL with a fragment might not scroll to the expected position.

Comment: Ah, the perfect solution, no extra JS.  This works beautifully when your header bar is floating and so hides the entire top part of the anchored position.

Comment: This answer is great (2022) but I feel like scrollIntoView should just have this as an option with offset anyway.

Comment: Promoted your answer as I believe it is better for performance reasons. Hope it will go higher soon :)

Comment: @Arseniy-II That's nice of you. Thank you! Lurkers appreciate it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me I can't believe this is is so hard

Comment: It's not working in case "overflow: hidden" and "display: inline". Described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70212566/the-scroll-margin-top-property-is-sometimes-not-working

Comment: This is the best solution if you are using scrollIntoView!

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: best answer. no need to locate the elements y position

Answer (score 142):

## Position Anchor By Absolute Method

Another way to do this is to position your anchors exactly where you want on the page rather than relying on scrolling by offset. I find it allows better control for each element (eg. if you want a different offset for certain elements), and may also be more resistant to browser API changes/differences.

```
<div id="title-element" style="position: relative;">
  <div id="anchor-name" style="position: absolute; top: -100px; left: 0"></div>
</div>
```

Now the offset is specified as -100px relative to the element. Create a function to create this anchor for code reuse, or if you are using a modern JS framework such as React do this by creating a component that renders your anchor, and pass in the anchor name and alignment for each element, which may or may not be the same.

Then just use :

```
const element = document.getElementById('anchor-name')
element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
```

For smooth scrolling with an offset of 100px.

Comment: This is especially useful when a "page top" type link is below a nav bar, and you want to show the nav, but don't want any other links offset

Comment: you can achieve the same using negative margin-top, you avoid of wrapping the element along with another with position relative

Answer (score 121):

You can do it in two steps :

```
el.scrollIntoView(true);
window.scrollBy(0, -10); // Adjust scrolling with a negative value here
```

Comment: If the `scrollIntoView()` hasn't finished scrolling before `scrollBy()` runs, the latter scroll will cancel the former.  At least on Chrome 71.

Comment: In this case use the setTimeout as seen in an answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51935129/1856258 .. For me it works without Timeout. Thanks!

Comment: is there a way to directly inject a pixel's corrector into scrollIntoView in order to make the application move directly to the relevant place? Like `scrollIntoView({adjustment:y})`, I think it should be possible with a custom code at the end

Comment: Expanding on what @DaveHughes has already said. Scroll will cancel if scroll mode is `smooth`, this works well and apparently there is no stutter as long as scroll mode is `instant`.

Answer (score 99):

I solved this problem by using,

```js
element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
```

This makes the element appear in the `center` after scrolling, so I don't have to calculate `yOffset`.

Hope it helps...

Comment: You should use `scrollTo` not on `element` but on `window`

Comment: @Arseniy-II Thanks for pointing that out!!. I missed that part!

Comment: does the block helps for top?

Comment: My scroll was just off a little bit! it worked with this! thanks!

Comment: Nice this should be top comment!

Comment: This doen't work if your element is higher than the viewport.

Comment: Works like a charm for scrolling into a dropdown div ! Thank you very much

Answer (score 55):

This works for me in Chrome (With smooth scrolling and no timing hacks)

It just moves the element, initiates the scroll, then moves it back.

There is no visible "popping" if the element is already on the screen.

```
pos = targetEle.style.position;
top = targetEle.style.top;
targetEle.style.position = 'relative';
targetEle.style.top = '-20px';
targetEle.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'});
targetEle.style.top = top;
targetEle.style.position = pos;
```

Comment: This is the best solution... Wish it was marked as answer. Would have saved a couple hours.

Comment: Tested it and it works out of the box. Not a hack and works great! Vote this one up!

Comment: Amazing. This way (storing style.top, setting to -x and reapplying it later after scrollIntoView is the only thing that works in Blazor and actually works. Using it with Virtualize component to show lot of data. Was shocked to learn there isn't scrolling supported by any means!! Thanks

Comment: Perfect!! I had to login to like you :)))

Answer (score 30):

## Fix it in 20 seconds:

This solution belongs to [@Arseniy-II](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56391657/4781067), I have just simplified it into a function.

```
function _scrollTo(selector, yOffset = 0){
  const el = document.querySelector(selector);
  const y = el.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset + yOffset;

  window.scrollTo({top: y, behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

Usage (you can open up the console right here in StackOverflow and test it out):

```
_scrollTo('#question-header', 0);
```

I'm currently using this in production and it is working just fine.

Comment: This worked a treat for me, I also added a line to dynamically determine the offset required.  My content was sitting under the nav, so I fetched the nav height to be passed in as yOffset

```const yOffset = document.getElementById('nav_id').getBoundingClientRect().height```

I also had to modify slightly to `-` the `yOffset` rather than `+`, as my content was scrolled too far up the page (under the nav)

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way to do this,

```
html, body {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

    html [id], body [id] {
        scroll-margin: 50px !important;
    }
```

with your provided code

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var el = document.getElementById(pathArray[5]);
el.style.scrollMargin = '50px';
el.scrollIntoView(true);
```

Comment: this is the right solution. it is generic and thus applying to everything on the page, but it is the right concept. thanks @malik zahid

Answer (score 10):

Another solution is to use "offsetTop", like this:

```
var elementPosition = document.getElementById('id').offsetTop;

window.scrollTo({
  top: elementPosition - 10, //add your necessary value
  behavior: "smooth"  //Smooth transition to roll
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you want to scroll to the divs that are all at the same level in DOM and have class name "scroll-with-offset", then this CSS will solve the issue:

```
.scroll-with-offset {    
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
}
```

The offset from the top of the page is 100px. It will only work as intended with block: 'start':

```
element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
```

What's happening is that the divs' top point is at the normal location but their inner contents start 100px below the normal location. That's what padding-top:100px is for. margin-bottom: -100px is to offset the below div's extra margin.
To make the solution complete also add this CSS to offset the margins/paddings for the top-most and bottom-most divs:

```
.top-div {
  padding-top: 0;
}
.bottom-div {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Building on an earlier answer, I am doing this in an Angular5 project.

Started with:

```
// el.scrollIntoView(true);
el.scrollIntoView({
   behavior: 'smooth',
   block: 'start'
});
window.scrollBy(0, -10);
```

But this gave some problems and needed to setTimeout for the scrollBy() like this:

```
//window.scrollBy(0,-10);
setTimeout(() => {
  window.scrollBy(0,-10)
  }, 500);
```

And it works perfectly in MSIE11 and Chrome 68+.  I have not tested in FF.  500ms was the shortest delay I would venture.  Going lower sometimes failed as the smooth scroll had not yet completed.  Adjust as required for your own project.

+1 to [Fred727](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2761887/fred727)  for this simple but effective solution.

Comment: This feels a bit janky to smooth scroll to an element and then scroll up a bit after.

Answer (score 5):

I've got this and it works brilliantly for me:

```
// add a smooth scroll to element
scroll(el) {
el.scrollIntoView({
  behavior: 'smooth',
  block: 'start'});

setTimeout(() => {
window.scrollBy(0, -40);
}, 500);}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: doesnt work in vue, sometimes the scroll posisition missed

Answer (score 4):

So, perhaps this is a bit clunky but so far so good. Im working in angular 9.

file `.ts`

```
scroll(el: HTMLElement) {
  el.scrollIntoView({ block: 'start',  behavior: 'smooth' });   
}
```

file `.html`

```
<button (click)="scroll(target)"></button>
<div  #target style="margin-top:-50px;padding-top: 50px;" ></div>
```

I adjust the offset with margin and padding top.

Saludos!

Answer (score 4):

**2022 pure js, smooth scrooling, and also works with reloaded content**

This is my solution for modern browsers:

```
document.addEventListener("click", e => {
   let anchorlink = e.target.closest('a[href^="#"]');
   
   if (anchorlink) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let hashval = anchorlink.getAttribute('href')
      let target = document.querySelector(hashval)
      const yOffset = -75;
      const y = target.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset + yOffset;
      window.scrollTo({ top: y, behavior: 'smooth' });
 
      history.pushState(null, null, hashval)
      e.preventDefault();
   }
})
```

The click-eventlistener listen to the document, so you don't have to worry about runtime loaded or created intern links (for example in wordpress with gutenberg)

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: This works flawlessly.

Comment: Works with react ref as well. I needed the very top of the component so I changed
`divRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height * -1`.  Also `pageYOffset` marked deprecated, changed it to `scrollY`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `element.scrollIntoView()` [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

```
el.scrollIntoView(
  { 
    behavior: 'smooth', 
    block: 'start' 
  },
);
```

which most browsers [support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview)

Comment: However this doesn't support any offset option.

Answer (score 2):

Solution if you are using Ionic Capacitor, Angular Material, and need to support iOS 11.

```
                document.activeElement.parentElement.parentElement.scrollIntoView({block: 'center', behavior: 'smooth'});
```

The key is to scroll to the parent of the parent which is the wrapper around the input.  This wrapper includes the label for the input which is now no longer cut off.

If you only need to support iOS 14 the "block" center param actually works, so this is sufficient:

```
                document.activeElement.scrollIntoView({block: 'center', behavior: 'smooth'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround solution. Say that you want to scroll to an div, Element here for example, and you want to have a spacing of 20px above it.
Set the ref to a created div above it:

`<div ref={yourRef} style={{position: 'relative', bottom: 20}}/>
<Element />`

Doing so will create this spacing that you want.

If you have a header, create an empty div as well behind the header and assign to it a height equal to the height of the header and reference it.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving my solution here in case of someone wanted to achieve the same as me.

In my case, the error or notification appears at the top of the page after submit. (the page is mostly bit long for a couple of scrolls and even more in mobile.)

I used the below snippet to scroll the error or notification into view.

```js
requestAnimationFrame(() =>
  errorOrNotification.scrollIntoView({
    block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth'
  })
);
```

`block: 'end'` is the trick. [As per documentation:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#parameters): It reflects the `alignToTop: false` scenario. In order to incorporate the `smooth` scrolling I added the replacement of the same.

> In essense, it will try to align the bottom of the element to the bottom of the visible area of the scrollable ancestor (in my case the window).

Answer (score 0):

My main idea is creating a **tempDiv** above the view which we want to scroll to. It work well without lagging in my project.

```
scrollToView = (element, offset) => {
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var targetY = rect.y + window.scrollY - offset;

    var tempDiv;
    tempDiv = document.getElementById("tempDiv");
    if (tempDiv) {
        tempDiv.style.top = targetY + "px";
    } else {
        tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
        tempDiv.id = "tempDiv";
        tempDiv.style.background = "#F00";
        tempDiv.style.width = "10px";
        tempDiv.style.height = "10px";
        tempDiv.style.position = "absolute";
        tempDiv.style.top = targetY + "px";
        document.body.appendChild(tempDiv);
    }

    tempDiv.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
}
```

**Example using**

```
onContactUsClick = () => {
    this.scrollToView(document.getElementById("contact-us"), 48);
}
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of Arseniy-II: I had the Use-Case where the scrolling entity was not window itself but a inner Template (in this case a div). In this scenario we need to set an ID for the scrolling container and get it via `getElementById` to use its scrolling function:

```html
<div class="scroll-container" id="app-content">
  ...
</div>
```

```js
const yOffsetForScroll = -100
const y = document.getElementById(this.idToScroll).getBoundingClientRect().top;
const main = document.getElementById('app-content');
main.scrollTo({
    top: y + main.scrollTop + yOffsetForScroll,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
```

Leaving it here in case someone faces a similar situation!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2 cents.

I've also had the issue of the scrollIntoView scrolling a bit past the element, so I created a script (native javascript) that prepends an element to the destination, positioned it a bit to the top with css and scrolled to that one. After scrolling, I remove the created elements again.

HTML:

```
//anchor tag that appears multiple times on the page
<a href="#" class="anchors__link js-anchor" data-target="schedule">
    <div class="anchors__text">
        Scroll to the schedule
    </div>
</a>

//The node we want to scroll to, somewhere on the page
<div id="schedule">
    //html
</div>
```

Javascript file:

```
(() => {
    'use strict';

    const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.js-anchor');

    //if there are no anchors found, don't run the script
    if (!anchors || anchors.length <= 0) return;

    anchors.forEach(anchor => {
        //get the target from the data attribute
        const target = anchor.dataset.target;

        //search for the destination element to scroll to
        const destination = document.querySelector(`#${target}`);
        //if the destination element does not exist, don't run the rest of the code
        if (!destination) return;

        anchor.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            //create a new element and add the `anchors__generated` class to it
            const generatedAnchor = document.createElement('div');
            generatedAnchor.classList.add('anchors__generated');

            //get the first child of the destination element, insert the generated element before it. (so the scrollIntoView function scrolls to the top of the element instead of the bottom)
            const firstChild = destination.firstChild;
            destination.insertBefore(generatedAnchor, firstChild);

            //finally fire the scrollIntoView function and make it animate "smoothly"
            generatedAnchor.scrollIntoView({
                behavior: "smooth",
                block: "start",
                inline: "start"
            });

            //remove the generated element after 1ms. We need the timeout so the scrollIntoView function has something to scroll to.
            setTimeout(() => {
                destination.removeChild(generatedAnchor);
            }, 1);
        })
    })
})();
```

CSS:

```
.anchors__generated {
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
}
```

Hope this helps anyone!

Answer (score 0):

I add this css tips for those who not resolved this issue with solutions above :

```
#myDiv::before {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  margin-top: -90px; // adjust this with your header height
  height: 90px; // adjust this with your header height
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### UPD: I've created an [npm package](https://github.com/DZakh/Smooth-smooth-scroll) that works better than the following solution and easier to use.

## My smoothScroll function

I've taken the wonderful solution of Steve Banton and wrote a function that makes it more convenient to use. It'd be easier just to use `window.scroll()` or even `window.scrollBy()`, as I've tried before, but these two have some problems:

- Everything becomes junky after using them with a smooth behavior on.
- You can't prevent them anyhow and have to wait till the and of the scroll.
  So I hope my function will be useful for you. Also, there is a [lightweight polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smoothscroll-polyfill) that makes it work in Safari and even IE.

### Here is the code

Just copy it and mess up with it how ever you want.

```js
import smoothscroll from 'smoothscroll-polyfill';

smoothscroll.polyfill();

const prepareSmoothScroll = linkEl => {
  const EXTRA_OFFSET = 0;

  const destinationEl = document.getElementById(linkEl.dataset.smoothScrollTo);
  const blockOption = linkEl.dataset.smoothScrollBlock || 'start';

  if ((blockOption === 'start' || blockOption === 'end') && EXTRA_OFFSET) {
    const anchorEl = document.createElement('div');

    destinationEl.setAttribute('style', 'position: relative;');
    anchorEl.setAttribute('style', `position: absolute; top: -${EXTRA_OFFSET}px; left: 0;`);

    destinationEl.appendChild(anchorEl);

    linkEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
      anchorEl.scrollIntoView({
        block: blockOption,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    });
  }

  if (blockOption === 'center' || !EXTRA_OFFSET) {
    linkEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
      destinationEl.scrollIntoView({
        block: blockOption,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    });
  }
};

export const activateSmoothScroll = () => {
  const linkEls = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-smooth-scroll-to]')];

  linkEls.forEach(linkEl => prepareSmoothScroll(linkEl));
};
```

To make a link element just add the following data attribute:

```html
data-smooth-scroll-to="element-id"
```

Also you can set another attribute as an addtion

```html
data-smooth-scroll-block="center"
```

It represents the `block` option of the `scrollIntoView()` function. By default, it's `start`. Read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

### Finally

Adjust the smoothScroll function to your needs.

For example, if you have some fixed header (or I call it with the word `masthead`) you can do something like this:

```js
const mastheadEl = document.querySelector(someMastheadSelector);

// and add it's height to the EXTRA_OFFSET variable

const EXTRA_OFFSET = mastheadEl.offsetHeight - 3;
```

If you don't have such a case, then just delete it, why not :-D.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using some of the answers from above, but the scrolling would not work. After some digging around I noticed that the scroll positions were in fact very odd (even negative values) and it was caused by how Angular was rendering the pages in the `router-outlet`.

My solution was to compute the scroll position of the element starting from the  top of the page. I placed an element with id `start-of-page` at the beginning of the template and I obtained the scroll amount by subtracting the target fragment position.

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment => {
      try {
        // @ts-ignore
        // document.querySelector('#hero').scrollIntoView({behavior:smooth, block: "start", inline: "start"});
        // @ts-ignore
        // document.querySelector('#' + fragment).scrollIntoView({behavior:smooth, block: "start", inline: "start"});
        this._scrollTo('#' + fragment,0);
      } catch (e) { };
    });
  }

private _scrollTo(selector: any, yOffset = 0){
    const base = document.querySelector('#start-of-page');
    const el = document.querySelector(selector);
    // @ts-ignore
    const y = el.getBoundingClientRect().top - base.getBoundingClientRect().top; 
    window.scrollTo({top: y, behavior: 'smooth'});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create an invisible temporary element with an offset relative to the target, scroll to it, and then delete it. It's perhaps not ideal, but other solutions weren't working for me in the context I was working in. For example:

```
const createOffsetElement = (element) => {
    const offsetElement = document.createElement('div');
    offsetElement.style = `
        position: relative;
        top: -10em;
        height: 1px;
        width: 1px;
        visibility: hidden;
    `;
    const inputWrapper = element.closest('.ancestor-element-class');
    inputWrapper.appendChild(offsetElement);
    return offsetElement;
};

const scrollTo = (element) => {
    const offsetElement = createOffsetElement(element);
    offsetElement.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
    });
    offsetElement.remove();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

For an element in a table row, use JQuery to **get the row above the one you want**, and simply scroll to that row instead.

Suppose I have multiple rows in a table, some of which should be reviewed by and admin.  Each row requiring review has both and up and a down arrow to take you to the previous or next item for review.

Here's a complete example that should just run if you make a new HTML document in notepad and save it.  There's extra code to detect the top and bottom of our items for review so we don't throw any errors.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Scrolling Into View</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        div.scroll { height: 6em; width: 20em; overflow: auto; }
        thead th   { position: sticky; top: -1px; background: #fff; }
        .up, .down { cursor: pointer; }
        .up:hover, .down:hover { color: blue; text-decoration:underline; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='scroll'>
<table border='1'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Review</th>
            <th>Data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id='row_1'>
            <th></th>
            <td>Row 1 (OK)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='row_2'>
            <th></th>
            <td>Row 2 (OK)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='row_3'>
            <th id='jump_1'><span class='up'>UP</span> <span class='down'>DN</span></th>
            <td>Row 3 (REVIEW)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='row_4'>
            <th></th>
            <td>Row 4 (OK)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='row_5'>
            <th id='jump_2'><span class='up'>UP</span> <span class='down'>DN</span></th>
            <td>Row 5 (REVIEW)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='row_6'>
            <th></th>
            <td>Row 6 (OK)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='row_7'>
            <th></th>
            <td>Row 7 (OK)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='row_8'>
            <th id='jump_3'><span class='up'>UP</span> <span class='down'>DN</span></th>
            <td>Row 8 (REVIEW)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='row_9'>
            <th></th>
            <td>Row 9 (OK)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='row_10'>
            <th></th>
            <td>Row 10 (OK)</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.up').on('click', function() {
        var id = parseInt($(this).parent().attr('id').split('_')[1]);
        if (id>1) {
            var row_id = $('#jump_' + (id - 1)).parent().attr('id').split('_')[1];
            document.getElementById('row_' + (row_id-1)).scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'});
        } else {
            alert('At first');
        }
    });

    $('.down').on('click', function() {
        var id = parseInt($(this).parent().attr('id').split('_')[1]);
        if ($('#jump_' + (id + 1)).length) {
            var row_id = $('#jump_' + (id + 1)).parent().attr('id').split('_')[1];
            document.getElementById('row_' + (row_id-1)).scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'});
        } else {
            alert('At last');
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```