# Vue-router redirect to hash with timeout

Tags: vue.js, hash, vuejs2, vue-router

I have route like this:

```
{
    path: '/kontakt',
    redirect: '#contact',
    component: index
},
```

and scrollBehavior:

```
scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (savedPosition) {
        return savedPosition
    }
    if(!to.hash) {
        return {
            x: 0, y: 0
        }
    }
    if(to.hash) {
        return {
            selector: to.hash
        }
    }
}
```

and IMO because I display my page 1 second after user actually enter it (I show logo for 1sec) above code doesn't scroll page to `#contact` div when I enter `/kontakt` route.

app.vue

```
<div v-show="timeGap">
    <router-view />
</div>
```

here timeGap is changed to true after 1sec in `setTimeout` method. How to fix so it scroll to #contact div after this timeout?

Comment: Can you provide a complete example somewhere on codepen or like that?

Comment: Can't really reproduce entire SPA with routing within code playground.

Comment: You can create `Vue.js` + `vue-router` example on codepen + `setTimeout` or what you are using and it will be much better to find what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the control of your scrolling behaviour from your router `scrollBehavior` handler to your component `index` and there into the place that knows the logo show state is `off`.

This might be:

- a Vue [lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) (either `mounted` or `updated`);
- or other point in this component that knows the logo state ([`watch` after `computed`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) ?);

As soon as you find that place (`watch`) in your component you have to check if the logo state is off and do your scroll using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56391657/6597265).