# Scroll into view in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have an HTML code, having a big table. and  I need to scroll to access all of the rows.

And I made the `thead` as a sticky tag. because I need this tag everywhere. (`position: sticky; top: 0;`)

But, when I want to use `firstCell.scrollIntoView();` in JavaScript, `firstCell` will be covered by `thead`!

You can see the sample in [this link](https://codepen.io/mhsarmadi/pen/qBVjeZY)

In this example, the `Target` is the first `cell` in the Table, and by clicking the button, it has to scroll into view of the `Target`

but `Target` will be at the backside of `thead`

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scrollIntoView Scrolls just too far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665602/scrollintoview-scrolls-just-too-far)

Comment: no, please open the link.

Comment: you can use  `document.getElementById('target').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest"});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `thead` has a sticky position, its size doesn't get taken into account when calculating the available space.

A workaround would be using `scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end' })` in place of `scrollIntoView()`.

This only works because the height of the `thead` is equal to the height of the `tr`, so if it aligns the scroll to the bottom, it's not covered anymore.

Answer (score 2):

After scrolling into view, check if the bottom of the head overlaps the top of the target by taking their [`getBoundingClientRect`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). If so, call `window.scrollBy` by the difference.

```js
const headTr = document.querySelector('thead tr');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const target = document.getElementById('target');
  target.scrollIntoView();
  const diff = target.getBoundingClientRect().top - target.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
  if (diff < 0) {
    window.scrollBy(0, diff);
  }
});
```

```html
<button style="position: fixed; top: 5px; right: 5px;">ScrollIntoView (for Target)</button>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr style='position: sticky; top: 0;'>
      <td>XYZ</td>
      <td>XYZ</td>
      <td>XYZ</td>
      <td>XYZ</td>
      <td>XYZ</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id=target style="color: red;">Target</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've to admit this is a better solution than the one proposed by me

Comment: oh it works, but how? whats the difference between bottom and top of the ```Target```?

Comment: See [the link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) in my answer that shows the values returned by `getBoundingClientRect` - specifically, [this image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect/element-box-diagram.png)

Comment: and, i think it works, when the height of tr(in tbody) is equal to height of tr(in thead); right?

Comment: No, his solution works for any height

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue but found an [article solving this issue](https://www.bram.us/2020/03/01/prevent-content-from-being-hidden-underneath-a-fixed-header-by-using-scroll-margin-top/) with CSS.
In my case, this was much easier to implement and handle.

If you append `scroll-margin-top` to a tag it will add the margin to that element automatically when `scrollIntoView()` is called.

```css
#target{
  scroll-margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
      <button onclick="document.getElementById('target').scrollIntoView();" style="position: fixed; top: 5px; right: 5px;">ScrollIntoView (for Target)</button>
      <table>
            <thead>
                  <tr style='position: sticky; top: 0;'>
                        <td>XYZ</td>
                        <td>XYZ</td>
                        <td>XYZ</td>
                        <td>XYZ</td>
                        <td>XYZ</td>
                  </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                  <tr>
                        <td id=target style="color: red;">Target</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>abc</td>
                  </tr>
            </tbody>
      </table>
</body>
</html>
```